# Detect when any part of a collider leaves a trigger zone on Unity 3D

Tags: unity, collider

I've searched all over for a simple solution on this, and found posts as old as 2011, with a bunch of hackish ways to badly work this out.

I want to detect when ANY part of a collider leaves a trigger area.

[image]

Some solutions I found and why they won't work on my case:

Using onTriggerExit will only trigger when the collider is COMPLETELY out of the trigger area, making it not ideal for boundaries of maps.

Calculating using bounds may work, but a bit complex when using a polygon collider with convex shapes.

I'm new to Unity and I'd guess this would be a pretty simple, default behaviour for many games.. Really surprised me that I found zero good answers for this on the web (both in stack exchange and Unity forums). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably late but, have you tried the opposite? Instead of creating a trigger area to detect when the collider leaves, create a surrounding area and detect when the collider enters. The enter activates whenever the first pixel enters the trigger and seems like that's what you need.